# How can I plus a value with null?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE qanda SET amount = amount + 1000 WHERE id = ? AND type = 0;
```

`amount` column is `null` by default and when I execute query above, nothing happens. How can I fix the problem? I guess I need casting.

Comment: Use `COALESCE(amount, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE qanda SET amount = nvl(amount,0) + 1000 WHERE id = ? AND type = 0;

Comment: Explain What You Have Used in sql

Comment: NVL() is an oracle function, this question is tagged mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  IFNULL() Function. It will return

```
UPDATE qanda SET amount = ifnull(amount,0) + 1000 WHERE id = ? AND type = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI standard function is `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE qanda
    SET amount = COALESCE(amount, 0) + 100
    WHERE id = ? AND type = 0;
```

Some databases have other arcane functions to do the same thing . . . `nz()`, `ifnull()`, `nvl()`, for example.  Stick with the standard when you can.

I should note that you might be able to fix this "problem" in another way.  When you define the column, give it a default value:

```
create table quanda (
    . . . 
    amount int not null default 0
    . . .
);
```

This will ensure that `NULL` is never in the column.